# For loop: How can I pause it after 100 loops for x seconds?

Tags: python

I have the following `for loop`:

```
for user_id in new_followers:
    try:    
        t.direct_messages.new(user_id=user_id, text="Thanks for following. Etc etc etc")
        print("Sent DM to %d" % (user_id))
        followers_old.add(user_id)
```

To avoid API limitations, I want to pause the loop for 600 seconds each time 100 direct messages are sent.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: @vaultah not really. I know how to sleep a python program, but my question is about sleeping it after X loops have been done.

Comment: you can use time.sleep(x), here x is in mili sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for i, user_id in enumerate(new_followers):
    try:    
        t.direct_messages.new(user_id=user_id, text="Thanks for following. Etc etc etc")
        print("Sent DM to %d" % (user_id))
        followers_old.add(user_id)
        if (i+1)%100 == 0:
             time.sleep(x) # here x in milisecond
```

Comment: It should probably be `== 99`, though. Also, `time.sleep` takes seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: `i+1 % 100` won't do what you want in most languages.  Is Python different here, or do you need parens to override the precedence of `%`?

Comment: yeaaa thanks for notification, i missed that

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
import time

count = 0

for user_id in new_followers:
    count +=1 
    if count == 100:
        count = 0
        time.sleep(600)
    try:    
        t.direct_messages.new(user_id=user_id, text="Thanks for following. Etc etc etc")
        print("Sent DM to %d" % (user_id))
        followers_old.add(user_id)
```

Comment: Man we were like sharks to chum on this question!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `counter` within the loop, counting up to 100 messages.
2. When `counter == 100`, use

   ```
   from time import sleep
   sleep(AMOUNT_OF_TIME)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import time
```

and then

```
time.sleep(seconds)
```

to sleep. You can use floats for smaller time than a second.

One thing to note, people will likely hate you if you do this.

Comment: My question is about sleeping it after X loops have been done.